# standalone application classpath entry using maven

Tags: java, maven-3, maven-assembly-plugin, maven-release-plugin, maven-jar-plugin

We are using maven for our standalone applications.currently we have two standalone application for new project and going forward it would increase. So I've deployment approach for all standalone application with dependency jars.

All application will have common jars like(spring and other open source jars), third party jars like proprietary mq,sybase and proprietary own jars and am planning to use different classpath prefix in jar plugin and came across `customClasspathLayout` tag in jar plugin but am not able to configure based on my above deployment structure.

For example, project 1 with below classpath entries

```
/jars/thirdparty/opensource/ (spring and other open source jars)
/jars/thirdparty/proprietary/ (mq and sybase and product jars)
/jars/company/ (all our company based api jars from internal nexus repository)
```

If required we will use application prefix before jars, I can add manual entry in jar plugin to add in manifest but i would like to configure based the source repository or some other standard approach, so that i can execute assembly plugin for profile like ( only opensource or only proprietary or only company or only application or entire dependency and application). I need to have fine control on jar location.

I though of this approach for two reasons,

1. I need to differentiate classpath location for different set of jars
2. Reduce the packaging based on need (mostly we will have application change rarely with product proprietary jars or sometimes with opensource up-gradation which could be based on stable opensource release.

Please suggest me is this possible and also welcome the feedback for different or better approach for classpath and deployment structure.

Comment: need something like this in classpath entry /jars/spring/(all spring jars)
/jars/thridparty/(all proprietary jars) 
/jars/properietary/(all company jars)

Comment: I would prefer to keep the jars as a `Maven Repository-Style` and then use the `classpathLayoutType` as `repository`. By using this, I am able to manage the dependencies version easily. Some app require lib version 1, another app may use the lib version 2 as well.

Comment: Thanks @charlee ... I thought about it but when I login am may not be able to see all the jars in same directory... For example all spring jar as siblings..

Comment: If no other option , I will use Maven layout as you suggested